# How do you speed up creating new field in attribute table for huge amount of data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, large-datasets

In my attribute table for a shapefile, I am converting one field (Julian day) to another field (date) using the field calculator but I'm working with about 7.7 million rows.  QGIS has been running for about 17 hours and is half way done.  Is there a way to speed up this process?  I have QGIS 2.14.19 Essen, not sure if upgrading to 2.18 would be faster.

Comment: You can probably try `Field Calculator` from `Layer Properties | Fields (tab)`, with which I tested successfully with an expression we have discussed recently. But I am afraid this can be a duplicate of [How to edit a large shapefile in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245935/how-to-edit-a-large-shapefile-in-qgis)

Comment: I can try it but how is it different from using the field calculator via the attribute table?

Comment: Are you using a Linux-enabled toaster oven with a 60hz CPU? Is your data file on network-shared thumb drive? There's  no way an update on a shapefile attribute should take more than 20-30 minutes, but there's no way to tell what's wrong with your process without being given details of the platform and data storage.

Comment: I'm using a Windows computer (a Dell) with 64-bit i7 and 12 GB of RAM.  The shapefile I'm updating is about 0.6 GB and is stored directly on my network.  I think it has more to do with how large the file is/the limits of QGIS rather than my computer.

Comment: What does "directly on my network" mean?

Comment: The shapefile is stored on my computer.  (i.e., not using a thumb drive or a server).

Comment: Yes, by not having to open the attribute table it reduces burden on QGIS to refresh the table toward the end of the process. (sorry for this tardy reply btw.)

Comment: aaah, please see the answer provided by @ndawson.

Comment: So I tried it through layer properties and creating the new field went quickly but now I'm having problems saving the changes.  I've left the program open for >1 hr and now QGIS isn't responding...

Comment: So I can create a new field under Layer | Properties of my massive amount of data, relatively quickly, but only in QGIS 2.14 (not QGIS 2.18).  However, QGIS 2.18 was great for clipping my very large shapefile (see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258518/how-to-clip-very-large-shapefile-in-qgis-using-ogr2ogr).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do it through the attribute table, or with any attribute tables open. Instead create new attributes directly though layer properties or via the field calculator from the main window.

Adding/deleting columns with attribute tables open is super-slow.

Comment: So I tried it through layer properties and creating the new field went quickly but now it's taking a very long time to save (an hour and counting)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have any open attribute tables (maybe hidden behind the main window) when you added the attribute/saved?

Comment: I'm positive. Everything runs smoothly until I turn off editing mode and save my new field

Comment: OK, so it wasn't working on QGIS 2.18 but it worked on QGIS 2.14!