# Large shapefile ... QGIS field calculator crashes

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area

I have a shapefile with more than 180,000 rows. Whenever I want to apply the field calculator (e.g. for $id or $area), QGIS crashes (*waiting to respond*). My PC has 32GB RAM.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: When I faced with this problem I started use SpatiaLite database. There you could make same result in 1-2 minutes. If it interesting I might explain step by step all process.

Comment: Can you share the file? I suspect there's some corruption here and would like to investigate

Comment: I would like to but unfortunately I am not allowed to share the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I came across the correct answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258567/how-do-you-speed-up-creating-new-field-in-attribute-table-for-huge-amount-of-dat)! Don't use the attribute table but rather use the field calculator directly from the main window. Worked well forme! Took only a minute or so. Solved, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the field calculator from the main window.

Adding/deleting columns with attribute tables open is super-slow.

Comment: Actually to be a bit more precise: close the attribute table while running the calculator on large datasets.

Answer (score 2):

This may well be a matter of patience. I've used the field calculator ($x and $y) on points layers with over 10 million features. Using a 16BG RAM PC, I also get the apparent crash of 'waiting to respond', but it still goes onward, and does provide results after a while (in my case, after a couple of hours).

I've used a SpatiaLite format, which runs much quicker than the CSV format that this data was originally in.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, I would create a spatial index for the file.

This may help.

[image]

Comment: I've tried to create a SpatiaLite index but that doesn't change anything. Is there a prefered file format for large field calculations? Should I use QGIS 2.X or QGIS 3.X?

Comment: This answer walks you through adding a spatial index to your existing shapefile. It's a completely different process from converting your shapefile into a SpatiaLite database.